# Filter an observed array with a observable condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a request, which returns an array of objects. Each object includes an id, with which I send another request. Based on this result I want to filter the array. Simplified example:

```
function getAllObjects(): Observable<{ id: number }[]> {
  return of([
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
  ]);
}

function checkObject(obj): Observable<boolean> {
  return of(obj.id % 2 === 0);
}

getAllObjects().pipe(
  // TODO
).subscribe(console.log); // I only want to see objects here which passed the async check
```

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. If you found a solution then you should write an answer. Edits should only be made to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Does that work for you?

```
getAllObjects().pipe(
  flatMap((ar) => ar),
  concatMap((obj) => combineLatest([of(obj), checkObject(obj)])),
  filter(([_, checkResult]) => checkResult),
  map(([obj]) => obj),
  toArray(),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Edit, I see you already found a solution, mine isn't much simpler, and I thought you wanted a stream of objects rather than return them as an array. So I added toArray in my Edit.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the same as I wrote in my edit. Do you think there is a simpler solution?

Comment: I don't know if there is a simpler solution. I am going to watch this question to find if someone else can figure a simpler solution. I am curious to know if one exists myself.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that may not be the simplest but it also works

```
getAllObjects()
    .pipe(
        switchMap(array =>
            combineLatest(array
                .map(obj =>
                    checkObject(obj)
                        .pipe(
                            distinctUntilChanged(),
                            map(boolean => boolean ? obj : null)
                        )
                )
            )
        ),
        map(array => array.filter(obj => obj))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Taking into account possible changes in real time

```
function getAllObjects(): Observable<{ id: number }[]> {
    return timer(0, 10000)
        .pipe(
            map(() => [
                { id: 1 },
                { id: 2 },
                { id: 3 },
                { id: 4 },
            ])
        );
}

function checkObject(obj): Observable<boolean> {
    return timer(1000, 5000)
        .pipe(
            map(() => obj.id % 2 === 0)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const objects$ = getAllObjects().pipe(concatAll());
const objectValidations$ = objects$.pipe(concatMap(checkObject));

zip(objects$, objectValidations$).pipe(
    filter(([, validated]) => validated),
    map(([obj,]) => obj),
    toArray()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

**UPDATE**:
We can improve the above solution performance-wise by parallelizing the "checks":

```
getAllObjects().pipe(
  concatAll(),
  mergeMap(obj => 
    checkObject(obj).pipe(
      map(isValid => isValid? obj : undefined),
      filter(Boolean),
    )
  ),
  toArray()
)
```

That's better because if we assume the following implementation of `checkObject` (added a delay):

```
function checkObject(obj) {
  return of(obj.id % 2 === 0).pipe(delay(1000));
}
```

Then for n objects, the previous solution takes n seconds, as opposed to 1 second with the updated solution

Answer (score -1):

```
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';


map(items => items.filter(item => item.id % 2 === 0)),
filter(items => items && items.length > 0)
```

First use the map function and filter the array like normal.
Then to make sure you don't get null or empty arrays, use the filter function which won't call the subscription if the map is null or empty.

Comment: The modulo was only simplified. The predicate is asynchronous in my case, I tried to point that out.

Comment: How about making the async call and based on the answer execute your code?
So the first subscription triggers the async predicate and based on the answer you call another function or you return?